# Storing value from text field in object, Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to update my object with values from text fields.

I think the problem is with the click eventhandler on the button but not sure. I've tried a few things, Your help would be amazing.

HTML

```
<form>
    <label><p>Book Name: </p></label>
    <input name="booktitle" id="booktitle" type="text" value="I'm a value">
    <label><p>Total Pages: </p></label>
    <input type="text">
    <label><p>Current Page: </p></label>
    <input type="text">
    <button id="my-Btn" type="button">Add to List</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
(function() {
// Create book object

var book = {

    name: 'JavaScript & jQuery',
    totalPages: 622,
    pages: 162,
    pagesLeft: function() {
        var total = this.totalPages - this.pages;
        return total;
    },
    percentageLeft: function() {
        var totalPercentage = this.pagesLeft() / this.totalPages * 100
        return Math.round(totalPercentage);
    }
};

// write out book name and pages info

var bookName, totalPages, pagesLeft, percentageLeft; //declares variables

bookName = document.getElementById('bookName'); // gets elements from document
totalPages = document.getElementById('totalPages');
pagesLeft = document.getElementById('pagesLeft');
percentageLeft = document.getElementById('percentageLeft');

bookName.textContent = book.name; // write to document
totalPages.textContent = 'Total Pages: ' + book.totalPages;
pagesLeft.textContent = book.pagesLeft();
percentageLeft.textContent = book.percentageLeft() + '%';

// pull value from text field and set to object

document.getElementById("my-Btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    book.name = document.getElementById('booktitle').value;
});

}());
```

Code Pen of what I have so far.

http://codepen.io/Middi/pen/pRGOVW

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code already updates an object's property (`book.name`) with a value from a text field (`#booktitle`). You can see this by adding `alert(book.name);` after the line

```
book.name = document.getElementById('booktitle').value;
```

As Jazcash noted, if you wanted to display the updated book name everytime it was changed, you'd need to add

```
bookName.textContent = book.name;
```

In your eventlistener, so it'd look something like this:

```
document.getElementById("my-Btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    book.name = document.getElementById('booktitle').value;
    bookName.textContent = book.name;
});
```

Comment: Awesome man. Thank you. you saved me from pulling my hair out

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're setting your divs textContent based on `book` here: `bookName.textContent = book.name;`. But then you need to do it again in your event like so:

```
book.name = bookName.value;
bookName.textContent = book.name;
```

You'll need to do this for all your fields

Comment: Legendary, Thank you so much